# Excel or POI changes my date format to something that doesn't work

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I've got an Excel file I want to recreate through POI. The existing Excel file uses as DataFormat `_(* #.##0_);_(* (#.##0);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)`. But when I assign that data format through POI, the resulting Excel file will instead use `_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)`. Note the tiny difference: a dot changed to a comma. Because of this, the entire format doesn't work anymore. It's not like it's now showing a comma where it used to have a dot; it's formatting the entire value in a completely different way.

Why does this happen? And how do I fix it?

The correct format string `_(* #.##0_);_(* (#.##0);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)` results in the number being displayed as `13.534.000`.

The incorrect format string that Excel or POI changes it to, `_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)` formats the value as `13534000,0`.

It's a complete mystery to me why it would do that. I suppose it has something to do with the US and Europe using different formats to display big numbers, but I would imagine that that's exactly what this data format is supposed to address. Instead, it turns it into nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache POI creates Microsoft Office files. Those files **never** are localized. They **always** store data in en_US locale. The locale dependent adjustments are done in locale Office applications then. So a Microsoft Office file can be sent around the world without the need to change the stored data to a foreign locale.

So if you set the data format using ...

```java
...
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  DataFormat dataformat = workbook.createDataFormat();
  CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellStyle.setDataFormat(dataformat.getFormat("_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* \"-\"??_);_(@_)"));
...
```

... the format pattern always needs to be en_US. That means dot is decimal separator, comma is thousands delimiter. A locale Excel application might adjust that to `_(* #.##0_);_(* (#.##0);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)` then.

Let's have a complete example:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class CreateExcelNumberFormat {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  DataFormat dataformat = workbook.createDataFormat();
  CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellStyle.setDataFormat(dataformat.getFormat("_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* \"-\"??_);_(@_)"));
  
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
  Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue(1234567.89);
  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
  
  row = sheet.createRow(1);
  cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue(-1234567.89);
  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

  sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 15*256);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateExcelNumberFormat.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

The result Excel file looks in my German Excel like so:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This explains the behaviour, or at least the first part. It's still weird that when I look at the data format string in Excel, it shows dots where the internal data format uses commas, and commas where the internal format uses dots.

I guess that's easy for users of Excel, because they don't need to even be aware of other localities, but it's extra confusing for POI users, because what looks like a standardised data format string isn't.